# How to make this java program to print?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, boolean

I am not sure what to do but I can't print anything with this. I am beginner in programming and kind of lost right now.
So the question is what I need to put in the `String integer = "";` to make this print something? I am using java. Thanks for help.

```
package myproject;

public class broke {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        
        boolean success = false;
         String integer = "";
            if(integer.indexOf("2") == 3){
                success = true;
            }
             if(success){
                System.out.println(integer);
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you copied that code from somewhere?

Comment: What is your guess? What *do* you understand about it?

Comment: Which part of that code is responsible for printing? When can it be executed? Does it depend on anything?

Comment: @Tom no I have not, it is part of homework I am working on

Comment: @JoachimSauer Even if I put `String integer = "3333";` it does not print anything, it is my second week trying to understand programming.

Comment: @elitenordic: what do you thinkg `integer.indexOf("2")` does? What could the `"2"` possibly indicate?

Comment: @JoachimSauer It checks the second index from the `string integer`. If that is 3 then it's true

Comment: @elitenordic: almost, but you've got it the wrong way around. Check [the JavaDoc of the `indexOf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Oh now I feel stupid... thanks a lot. I tried to do my own research but now I see that I didn't understand it right.

Comment: @elitenordic: it seems you just learned something. If anything you should feel less stupid now ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any string which has `2` at index, `3` will make the condition, `integer.indexOf("2") == 3` true. Note that the index starts from `0` in a string.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean success = false;
        String integer = "543210";
        if (integer.indexOf("2") == 3) {
            success = true;
        }
        if (success) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
543210
```

In the string, `543210`, the index of `5` is `0` and starting with this index, the index of `2` is `3`.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a String variable called "integer", and setting it's value to "" (an empty string).

```
System.out.println(integer);
```

The above snippet, if not for the weird if statement.. would print your string.. but your string is empty, so that printing would just consist of a \n being sent to System.out.

The reason nothing is printing is because the method call "string.indexOf("2")" returns -1 (indicating the character "2" was not found).

I saw in your comment you tried this with the string "3333", and again, expectedly, the character "2" would not be found.

I ran your code with setting String integer = "2", and it worked fine.

Maybe your confusion is how the indexOf() method, belonging to the String class, works. It returns the first index where the value passed in as a parameter occurs.

Comment: I know that, but thanks. I tried using `String integer = "3333";` for an example but I still didn’t make it to print.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the whole thing wrong. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

your program will only print when `success` is `true`, since the statement, `if(integer.indexOf("2") == 3)` is `false`(integer is empty), `success` will be `false`, thus `System.out.println(integer);` will not be executed.